# Restoring a PowerShell alias when a module is unloaded

Tags: powershell

How do I restore a PowerShell alias when my module has been unloaded.

The code I have so far does not work although executing the `Set-Alias` command by itself does. It stores the definition in a local variable, which is available when the `OnRemove` event is fired.

```
$orig_cd = (Get-Alias -Name 'cd').Definition
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Module.OnRemove = {
    Set-Alias -Name 'cd' -Value $orig_cd -Force -Option AllScope -Scope Global
}
```

I should also mention that I am overriding the existing cd command alias like so

```
Set-Alias -Name cd -Value cdX -Force -Option AllScope -Scope Global
```

Here is the source code to the module https://github.com/vincpa/z/blob/master/z.psm1

### Update

Adding a `Write-Host` command within the OnRemove handler shows that the value of `$orig_cd` is indeed `Set-Location`.

Comment: How about using a proxy function for Remove-Module that checks to see if it's your module being removed, and restores the alias first?

Comment: I haven't figured out what's going on with the OnRemove block and scopes yet, but have you considered leaving the default "cd" alias alone, and instead exporting a function named "Set-Location" from this module? The default cd alias will call this function for as long as the module is loaded, and will go back to calling the normal cmdlet when the module is removed.

Comment: I would try adding some output in your onremove handler, so you can discover just what the value of $orig_cd in that scope.  Modules and scopes are wonky together, they don't always work the way you expect.

Comment: Does PowerShell capture the alias being created somehow being part of the module which is unloaded?

Comment: You may also want to check out - http://github.com/manojlds/posz :)

Comment: @manojlds Wow, I thought I was the only one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this, and it works:

```
$orig_cd = (Get-Alias -Name 'cd').Definition
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Module.OnRemove = {
    set-item alias:cd -value $orig_cd
}

Set-item alias:cd -Value 'cdX'
```

Also, a suggestion - you are writing a module which people will use in their terminals. I don't expect a use case where some one would want to remove your module. These steps maybe overkill for the module you are writing.

Comment: You're assuming people will like my module after trying it out. If they don't, they'll most probably want to unload it. Yes it does matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Although [about_scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) is a bit confusing, the [Alias Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847895.aspx) looks like it has the key.

The alias is already scoped with `AllScope` which means children scope have copies/access. All you have to do is change the value.

Look at the switch `-Options` in `Set-Alias` - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849938.aspx

> -- AllScope: The alias is copied to any **new** scopes that are created.

```
#Override the existing CD command with the wrapper in order to log 'cd' commands.
Set-Item alias:cd -Value 'cdx'
Set-Alias -Name pushd -Value pushdX -Force -Option AllScope -Scope Global

$orig_cd = (Get-Alias -Name 'cd')
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Module.OnRemove = {
    set-item alias:cd -value 'set-content'
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function z, cdX, pushdX -alias ''
```

Comment: Once the module is unloaded, the 'cd' alias simply points to 'cd' rendering the command broken.